# Blackberry. Discover if it is being used and what version

Tags: javascript, jquery, blackberry

I have a mobile app I am creating with JQuery Mobile. When a blackberry is not being used I will send the user from a regular html page, to a page using JQuery Mobile (because of bb comparability issues)

This is how I do so:

```
    //Loads correct page for everything but blackberry
    if (!(/blackberry/i.test(navigator.userAgent))) {
        //Send to mobile page (for Droid and iPhone)
        window.location = "Mobile.htm";
    }
```

Which works fine, but I know that there are blackberries that can work with the most stable JQuery mobile release (platform 6+). Could I be able to add another condition to my if statement to detect that? The JQuery mobile pages look a lot nicer and if the BB platform 6 phones can use them, then I want them to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have any BlackBerrys to test this on, but I believe you can test **[jQuery.browser.version](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/#jQuery-browser-version2)**

If that doesn't work, you can sniff the version out of the user agent string.  Check out http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/How-to-detect-the-BlackBerry-Browser/ta-p/559862

Comment: That seems to work on my sims. Hopefully that means it works on a real bb